# Integrate JFROG artifactory with Azure Web App and Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, artifactory

I am trying to integrate JFROG artifactory with Azure webapps using CICD in AzureDevOps. So the workflow will be like this

- User pushes code to github
- Azure DevOps runs CI and send the artifact/code to JFROG artifactory
- JFROG updates the application on Azure Web App

The application is all in C#. I have already managed it to integrate with AKS but cant find and tutorial or guide for integrating JFROG with Azure App. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above post, this can be achieved by installing the JFrog Artifactory extension in your Azure DevOps Organization, but in your pipeline you will need tasks to upload (ArtifactoryUpload) and download (ArtifactoryDownload). so basically, here is what you will do:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build WebApp
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release --no-restore'

- task: ArtifactoryGenericUpload@2
  displayName: Publish webapp
  inputs:
    artifactoryService: 'artifactory'
    specSource: 'taskConfiguration'
    fileSpec: |
      {
        "files": [
          {
            "pattern": "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildNumber)/*.zip",
            "target": "$(artifactory)/$(Build.BuildNumber)"
          }
        ]
      }
    collectBuildInfo: false
    buildName: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
    buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    failNoOp: true

- task: ArtifactoryGenericDownload@3
  displayName: Download artifact
  inputs:
    connection: 'artifactory'
    specSource: 'taskConfiguration'
    fileSpec: |
      {
        "files": [
          {
            "pattern": "$(artifactory)/$(Build.BuildNumber)/*.zip",
            "target": "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/"
          }
        ]
      }
    failNoOp: true

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: Deploy AppService
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Subscription'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'webapp'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildNumber)/webapp.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking to integrate Artifactory with Azure DevOps, this can be achieved by installing the JFrog Artifactory extension [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension), and then configuring the build script accordingly.

You can refer to below JFrog wiki pages which helps you to achieve your use case:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension

https://jfrog.com/screencast/jfrog-artifactory-on-azure/

https://jfrog.com/webinar/effective-ci-cd-with-azure-devops-and-the-jfrog-platform/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4_veZaFDmQ

Comment: I'd recommend using the new JFrog extension instead of the old Artifactory extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-azure-devops-extension